# classify np.arrays as duplicates

Tags: python, numpy

My goal is to take a list of `np.array`s and create an associated list or array that classifies each as having a duplicate or not. Here's what I thought would work:

```
www = [np.array([1, 1, 1]), np.array([1, 1, 1]), np.array([2, 1, 1])]
uniques, counts = np.unique(www, axis = 0, return_counts = True)
counts = [1 if x > 1 else 0 for x in counts]
count_dict = dict(zip(uniques, counts))
[count_dict[i] for i in www]
```

The desired output for this case would be :

`[1, 1, 0]`

because the first and second element have another copy within the original list. It seems that the problem is that I cannot use a `np.array` as a key for a dictionary.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are all the arrays in `www` always the same size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert `www` to a 2D Numpy array then do the following:

```
In [18]: (counts[np.where((www[:,None] == uniques).all(2))[1]] > 1).astype(int)
Out[18]: array([1, 1, 0])
```

here we use broadcasting for check the equality of all `www` rows with `uniques` array and then using `all()` on last axis to find out which of its rows are completely equal to `uniques` rows.

Here's the elaborated results:

```
In [20]: (www[:,None] == uniques).all(2)
Out[20]: 
array([[ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False,  True]])

# Respective indices in `counts` array
In [21]: np.where((www[:,None] == uniques).all(2))[1]
Out[21]: array([0, 0, 1])

In [22]: counts[np.where((www[:,None] == uniques).all(2))[1]] > 1
Out[22]: array([ True,  True, False])

In [23]: (counts[np.where((www[:,None] == uniques).all(2))[1]] > 1).astype(int)
Out[23]: array([1, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, lists (and numpy arrays) cannot be hashed, so they can't be used as dictionary keys.  But tuples can!  So one option would be to convert your original list to a tuple, and to convert `uniques` to a tuple.  The following works for me:

```py
www = [np.array([1, 1, 1]), np.array([1, 1, 1]), np.array([2, 1, 1])]
www_tuples = [tuple(l) for l in www]  # list of tuples
uniques, counts = np.unique(www, axis = 0, return_counts = True)
counts = [1 if x > 1 else 0 for x in counts]
# convert uniques to tuples
uniques_tuples = [tuple(l) for l in uniques]
count_dict = dict(zip(uniques_tuples, counts))
[count_dict[i] for i in www_tuples]
```

Just a heads-up: this will double your memory consumption, so it may not be the best solution if `www` is large.
You can mitigate the extra memory consumption by ingesting your data as tuples instead of numpy arrays if possible.